# Mutually exclusive functions calling each other

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

I have two functions `foo` and `bar` that should be mutually exclusive since they operate on the same data. However `foo` duplicates a lot of code from `bar`, so I would like to refactor `foo` to make a call to `bar`.

This is a problem because then I can't use a single mutex for both functions, because then `foo` would deadlock when it calls `bar`. So rather than "mutually exclusive" I only want "mutually exclusive from different threads".

Is there a pattern for implementing this? I'm using C++ and I'm okay with C++14/boost if I need something like shared_mutex.

Comment: Using a `std::mutex` üerhaps?

Comment: Pass the mutex as a parameter to the refactored section of shared code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "üerhaps" sounds like a disease you bring home from a vacation, or maybe from a metal concert.

Comment: @KerrekSB [_Üüüps_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iwC2QljLn4) :-P ....

Comment: What you are describing is called a [Reentrant mutext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex). Googling the term with 'boost' returns [Recursive mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/thread/doc/recursive_mutex.html), which may be what you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Define a private "unlocked" function and use that from both `foo` and `bar`:

```
void bar_unlocked()
{
    // assert that mx_ is locked
    // real work
}

void bar()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mx_);
    bar_unlocked();
}

void foo()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mx_);
    // stuff
    bar_unlocked();
    // more stuff
}
```

Comment: quite obvious (had the same idea, but was here too late)

Answer (score 4):

another way - this has the advantage that you can prove that the lock has been taken:

```
void bar_impl(std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock)
{
   assert(lock.owns_lock());
    // real work
}

void bar()
{
    bar_impl(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mx_));
}

void foo()
{
    // stuff
    bar_impl(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mx_));
    // more stuff
}
```

Rationale:

`std::mutex` is not (mandated by the standard to be) moveable, but a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` is. For this reason, we can move a lock into a callee and return it back to a caller (if necessary).

This allows us to prove ownership of the lock at every stage of a call chain.

In addition, once the optimiser gets involved, it's likely that all the lock-moving will be optimised away. This gives us the best of both worlds - provable ownership and maximal performance.

A more complete example:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>

struct actor
{
  //
  // public interface
  //

  // perform a simple synchronous action
  void simple_action()
  {
    impl_simple_action(take_lock());
  }

  /// perform an action either now or asynchronously in the future
  /// hander() is called when the action is complete
  /// handler is a latch - i.e. it will be called exactly once
  /// @pre an existing handler must not be pending
  void complex_action(std::function<void()> handler)
  {
    impl_complex_action(take_lock(), std::move(handler));
  }

  private:

  //
  // private external interface (for callbacks)
  //
  void my_callback()
  {
    auto lock = take_lock();
    assert(!_condition_met);
    _condition_met = true;
    impl_condition_met(std::move(lock));
  }


  // private interface

  using mutex_type = std::mutex;
  using lock_type = std::unique_lock<mutex_type>;

  void impl_simple_action(const lock_type& lock)
  {
    // assert preconditions
    assert(lock.owns_lock());
    // actions here
  }

  void impl_complex_action(lock_type my_lock, std::function<void()> handler)
  {
    _handler = std::move(handler);
    if (_condition_met)
    {
      return impl_condition_met(std::move(my_lock));
    }
    else {
      // initiate some action that will result in my_callback() being called
      // some time later
    }
  }

  void impl_condition_met(lock_type lock)
  {
      assert(lock.owns_lock());
      assert(_condition_met);
      if(_handler)
      {
        _condition_met = false;
        auto copy = std::move(_handler);
        // unlock here because the callback may call back into our public interface
        lock.unlock();
        copy();
      }
  }



  auto take_lock() const -> lock_type
  {
    return lock_type(_mutex);
  }


  mutable mutex_type _mutex;

  std::function<void()> _handler = {};
  bool _condition_met = false;
};

void act(actor& a)
{
  a.complex_action([&a]{ 
    // other stuff...
    // note: calling another public interface function of a
    // during a handler initiated by a
    // the unlock() in impl_condition_met() makes this safe.
    a.simple_action(); 
  });

}
```

Comment: Is the `more stuff` still running with the mutex locked? `move a lock into a callee and return it back to a caller` Another option is passing reference.